# General dimensions for a uav type rc plane?

Tags: aircraft-design

I want to build an rc plane that looks like this one
[image]

What are the general dimensions that I should follow? I dont want to copy other designs of real uav's and scale them down. A drawing would be great

I want to build something small, wing span should be about 125 cm

Comment: What exactly are you asking for? If you're building it then I assume you already know how big you want it to be? And designing and building an aircraft - even a small one - is far too broad to answer here. Maybe you can break down what you need into several smaller, specific questions?

Comment: I second @Pondlife. For instance, how to scale just the wings or thrust of a plane.

Comment: The wing should be no more than 125cm wide

Comment: @zero First you need to work out your payload weight, and using interpolated data from similar aircraft what additional weight you need to assume is for engines and the airframe. from that you can scale the lift of the wings.

Answer (score 1):

You can start by looking at plans [here](http://www.rcfoam.com/free-rc-airplane-plans-a-free_rc_airplane_plans.html) to get a general idea. When it comes to planes you can't just get some "general" measurements and wing it (pun intended). There are a lot of considerations when it comes to making things fly. With out going into specifics it would be best to use known working plans to build something as apposed to trying to throw something together that looks right.

To Answer your question directly that picture looks like the wing span is the the 3.5 foot range, the center section is about 2.5 feet long and tail poles are about 18 inches.

Comment: That picture makes it hard to get a sense of scale, [the wingspan is actually 3 m](http://www.fpvflying.com/products/Mugin-3m-UAV-platform-%28TT%252dtail%29.html).

Comment: Oh man that is way bigger than it looks.